# How should I get rid of my hamsters?

Tags: hamsters

A year and a half ago I bought a couple of Russian hamsters and large cage.  My daughter had been pleading with me to get them for months.  We had to buy two, because apparently they get very lonely on their own.

It turns out they aren't such great pets. They are largely nocturnal, so my daughter rarely gets a chance to see them as they sleep much of the day.
Predictably, my daughter completely lost interest in the hamsters after about a month, so it was left to me and my wife to feed them and clean out their cage.  They don't seem happy and are always trying to gnaw through the bars in their cages.

After 3 months, they began fighting.  The fights got worse and worse so after googling this and learning they often fight to the death, we bought a new cage and separated them. We put the cages next to each other so they could still see each other, but without any murdering.

A few weeks ago, my wife was clearing them out when my daughter decided to put them together in a small cage we have for when we clean them out.  A fight broke out and my wife grabbed one of them, to separate them but it bit her hand. Hard. Through to the bone, she had to go to hospital about it as it swelled right up.

So at about this point, we are done with them.

I don't want to rehouse them as, a) they only have a life span of 2 years so haven't got long left and b) one of them is a biter.

I don't want to give them to an animal shelter as I've read that they will usually end up as pet snake food.

So I think my only remaining course of action is to drive out of town and release them in the wild.  I'm pretty sure they wouldn't last too long, but I'd bet they'd enjoy the initial freedom as they run through a field for the first time rather than running in their squeaky, rickety wheels.
Plus isn't it better to die on your feet than to live on your knees?

How bad a thing to do is it?  Is there a better way to get rid of them?

Comment: We gave our guinea pigs to the local school.

Comment: Releasing potentially invasive animals in the wild is way worse than use them as snake food or euthanizing them.

Comment: @Pere - true, but it's a pair of males so I doubt they will multiply.  Plus they hate each other.

Comment: I guess the responsible thing would be to just wait. If they really have only a two year life expectancy, that's only 6 months left.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where should I release a pet hamster to maximize its chance of survival?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/33016/where-should-i-release-a-pet-hamster-to-maximize-its-chance-of-survival)

Comment: You could try to find each of them a new home. Hamsters are loner, they want to be alone except for mating. So find two homes with people working and watching the hamsters in the evening.The "biter" did not aimed your wife, but this bothering other hamster- intruder and accidental hit this object coming between (the hand). Alone both of them will be nice little pets.

Comment: Not really my place, but it kinda is the elephant in the room here... maybe this is a teachable moment and very valuable lesson to learn in life for your daughter. If you accept responsibility for a pet (or any living being), there are no shortcuts, no dumping that responsibility on your parents, no easy way out. You wanted hamsters, you got hamsters, now you get to clean cages as long as your hamsters need you to.